# MainActivity not recognizing a variable assined in layout

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, kotlin

I'm currently, in my layout "activity_main.xml" defining a variable as

```
 android:id="@+id/viewPager"
```

without any error. later on - I tried to reference this variable in MainActivity with:

```
 viewPager.adapter = adapter
```

At this point an error is thrown "unresolved reference: viewPager"

Not sure why viewPager isn't being recognized.

Its my first day on Android Studio - sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Being able to use a layout ID directly in your Kotlin code is a feature provided by `kotlin-android-extensions`, which has recently been deprecated, so it is not available in newly created projects anymore. You can add `apply plugin: kotlin-android-extensions` to the top of your `app/build.gradle` file to get it to work, but since it's deprecated and they plan to permanently disable it by the end of the year, you should learn to use view binding instead. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Comment: @Tenfour04 - Thank you so much for this! I’ll check this alternative out and mark this as the answer if it solves the issue. It’s tough sifting through tutorials in when things are changing so quickly haha.